# Concatenate string list component into a string with comma separated

Tags: c#

I have a list of `string` (`List<String>`). I want to concatenate list items and form a new *comma separated string*. I am knew in C#. Please provide me best possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] myList = ...
string concatenated = string.Join("," myList);
```

Comment: It´s `Join`, not `join`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to create *CSV* (*Comma Separated Value*) string

```
  List<String> source = new List<String>() {
    "abc",   // just a string
    "d,e",   // string which contains comma
    "x\"yz", // string which contains quotation
  };

  String result = String.Join(",", source
    .Select(x => x.Contains(',') || x.Contains('"')
      ? "\"" + String.Concat(x.Select(c => c == '"' ? "\"\"" : c.ToString())) + "\""
      : x));

  ...

  // abc,"d,e","x""yz"
  Console.Write(result);
```

Note *quotations marks* added